# Can't back to Unity after install Pantheon

Tags: unity, pantheon

I tried install pantheon with no success and after that i tried go back to unity, but my desktop is ugly now. Tried logout/login and change to default, removed purge pantheon repositories, reset/replace unity. Simply i can't go back to Unity. I tried almost everything i read on web. Anyone can help me please?

Comment: Can you post a screenshot?

Answer (score 0):

Try reinstalling Unity from the Software Center. If that does not work, Backup everything and install a fresh copy of Ubuntu.

Comment: In the software center, I only find the Unity Tweak Tool (Ubuntu 16.04). Can Unity be reinstalled using this tool? If now, how reinstall unity?